# Can't use camera package

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I added [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera#-installing-tab-) to the `pubspec.yaml` file.

However, when I enter flutter packages get in the terminal, an error occurs.

[image: Error image]

Can I get advice on what to do?

Comment: What is your package/project name ? If it's `camera` change that to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your project name is also camera change your project name and it will run perfectly.